# Building Qiskit Aer from source generates Errors

Tags: build, compilation, qiskit

I need MPI support along with GPU (GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, CUDA driver version is 11.4 and running version is 10.1) for which I have to build qiskit-aer from source. My python version is 3.8.16. I have done installing all requirements mentioned in CONTRIBUTING.md. However running final command with required options;

```
python3 ./setup.py bdist_wheel -- -DAER_THRUST_BACKEND=CUDA -DAER_MPI=True
```

I am getting following Error which I am unable to resolve.

```
/usr/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(78): error: an rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue
      detected during:
        instantiation of "pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg...), const Extra &...) [with Return=void, Class=AER::AerState, Arg=<const AER::reg_t &, AER::cmatrix_t &&>, Extra=<pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling>]" 
(1112): here
        instantiation of "pybind11::class_<type_, options...> &pybind11::class_<type_, options...>::def(const char *, Func &&, const Extra &...) [with type_=AER::AerState, options=<>, Func=void (AER::AerState::*)(const AER::reg_t &, AER::cmatrix_t &&), Extra=<>]" 
/home/dell/vir/qiskit-aer-main/qiskit_aer/backends/wrappers/aer_state_binding.hpp(124): here
        instantiation of "void bind_aer_state(MODULE) [with MODULE=pybind11::module]" 
/home/dell/vir/qiskit-aer-main/qiskit_aer/backends/wrappers/bindings.cc(28): here

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000012da_00000000-6_bindings.cpp1.ii".
make[2]: *** [qiskit_aer/backends/wrappers/CMakeFiles/controller_wrappers.dir/build.make:76: qiskit_aer/backends/wrappers/CMakeFiles/controller_wrappers.dir/bindings.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:874: qiskit_aer/backends/wrappers/CMakeFiles/controller_wrappers.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dell/miniconda3/envs/QiskitDevEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 674, in setup
cmkr.make(make_args, install_target=cmake_install_target, env=env)
  File "/home/dell/miniconda3/envs/QiskitDevEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 697, in make
self.make_impl(clargs=clargs, config=config, source_dir=source_dir, install_target=install_target, env=env)
  File "/home/dell/miniconda3/envs/QiskitDevEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 742, in make_impl
raise SKBuildError(msg)

An error occurred while building with CMake.
Command:
/home/dell/miniconda3/envs/QiskitDevEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
  Install target:
  install
  Source directory:
/home/dell/vir/qiskit-aer-main
  Working directory:
/home/dell/vir/qiskit-aer-main/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.8/cmake-build
Please check the install target is valid and see CMake's output for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was removed by running `pip install "pybind11[global]"`.

For complete installation see [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zdcb3VcWtIWFpNO6B-zYbNzMvjB5Z8yX?usp=sharing#scrollTo=4Kykngh9ECXx).